# Can't create new SAP GUI connection using win32com.client in Python - troubleshooting help needed

Tags: python, authentication, rpa, sap-gui

I am trying to create a new SAP GUI connection using win32com.client in Python. I need to automate the process of creating a connection to a custom application server in SAP GUI. However, I'm encountering issues with the script.

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os


class Sap():
    def __init__(self, connection_name, application_server, instance_number, system_id, saprouter_string, client):
        '''
        Opens SAP GUI and creates a new connection.

        Args:
            connection_name (string): The name of the new SAP connection.
            description (string): The description of the new SAP connection.
            application_server (string): The application server of the SAP system.
            instance_number (string): The instance number of the SAP system.
            system_id (string): The system ID of the SAP system.
            saprouter_string (string): The SAProuter string.
            client (string): The client of the SAP system.

        '''
        logging.info('Opening Sap')

        self.path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
        self.sap_process = subprocess.Popen(self.path)
        time.sleep(5)  # wait until load
        self.SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
        if not type(self.SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            return
        application = self.SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngineControl()
        connection = application.OpenConnection(connection_name, True)
        session = connection.Children(0)

        # Create a new SAP connection
        sap_logon = application.CreateConnection()
        #sap_logon.Description = description
        sap_logon.ConnectionType = "Custom Application Server"
        sap_logon.ApplicationServer = application_server
        sap_logon.SystemID = system_id
        sap_logon.InstanceNumber = instance_number
        sap_logon.SAProuterString = saprouter_string
        sap_logon.Client = client
        sap_logon.Language = "EN"
        sap_logon.User = "username"
        sap_logon.Password = "password"

        # Add the new connection to SAP GUI
        connection.Children.Add(sap_logon)

        # Save and close the SAP logon configuration
        application.SaveConnectionList()
        application.Quit()

        # Reopen SAP GUI with the new connection
        subprocess.Popen(self.path)
        time.sleep(5)

        # Get the new connection and session
        self.SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
        if not type(self.SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            return
        application = self.SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine()
        connection = application.OpenConnection(connection_name, True)
        self.session = connection.Children(0)
        self.session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize()

    def login(self, client, user, password, language):
        '''
        Log in SAP.

        Args:
            client (string): The SAP client.
            user (string): The SAP user.
            password (string): The SAP user's password
            language (string): The SAP language.

        '''
        try:
            logging.info('Login Sap')

            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").text = client
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = user
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = password
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").text = language
            self.session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

            logging.info('Successfully logged in Sap')

        except:
            logging.error(f'Failed to Login SAP: {sys.exc_info()[0]}')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Log into SAPGUI using Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473217/how-to-log-into-sapgui-using-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to connect and login to SAP Logon via Python

```
import win32com.client
import subprocess

path = "<path to saplogon.exe>"
subprocess.Popen(path)
SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
OApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
connection = OApp.OpenConnection("Connection Name eg: TESTConn [127.0.0.1]", True)
session = connection.Children(0)
session.findbyId("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").text = '<client>'
session.findbyId("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = '<username>'
session.findbyId("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = '<password>'
session.findbyId("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").text = '<language>'
session.findbyId("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
```

a working example is available at [SAPKiln](https://github.com/OWASP/SAPKiln)